# How to create GlassPanel in GWT2.5 using uibinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt-2.5

Can anyone please suggest the best way to create a Glasspanel widget using UiBinder?.
I am using GWT version 2.5

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Dialog Box](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DialogBox.html), and set glassEnabled to true.